# How is possible in a python program to retrieve two different versions of the same csv file from a git repository?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, csv

It is possible in a Python script to get 2 versions of the same csv file from a git repository?

For example, in my repository, I have the following versions of the same csv file located at **C:\Users\Desktop\the_csv_file.csv**.

The history of this file is the following:

> **C:\Users\Desktop>git log --pretty=oneline**
> 64534ce132aa5ba5u6u424da1a19ac3f840368a6 (HEAD -> master) last version - version_4
> 26ff7u90fa988975b8e94bb7ca1ecee94ed8ea64 version_3
> b1c9b1200382b012c4c30284f2322bbb9c81a15f version_2
> f72520f9222c8fq3zze5a18d827b5f8b7405c954 version_1

How can I retrieve from that repository, for example, the version 3 and version 2 of the csv file located in **C:\Users\Desktop\** that is called the_csv_file.csv?

It is possible to retrieve the 26ff7u90fa988975b8e94bb7ca1ecee94ed8ea64 version (version 3) and the b1c9b1200382b012c4c30284f2322bbb9c81a15f  version (version 2) and put them into variables? like in the following example:

```py
with open(path_csv_file_version3, mode ='r', encoding= default_encoding) as file_old, open(path_csv_file_version4, mode ='r', encoding= default_encoding)as file:
        csv_new = csv.DictReader(file)
        csv_old = csv.DictReader(file_old)
```

something like that is possible?

Comment: is it sufficient to check out the version you need?

Comment: You can call a git executable with appropriate parameters from within Python or use a Python library to access the repository.